# how import the mod source file to test file in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

the structure of project like this:

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── demo.txt
├── src
│   ├── lib.rs
│   ├── lifetime_demo
│   │   └── mod.rs
│   ├── main.rs
└── tests
    └── trait_test.rs
```

the `mod.rs` of lifetime_demo path:

```rust
    pub mod lifetime_mod {
        pub fn show() {}
    }
```

the `test.rs` code

```rust
    use demo::lifetime_demo::lifetime_mod;
    #[test]
    fn test_trait() {
        lifetime_mod::show();
    }
```

when run 'cargo test' in /tests path, it tips error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `demo::lifetime_demo`
 --> tests/trait_test.rs:3:11
  |
3 | use demo::lifetime_demo::lifetime_mod;
  |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `lifetime_demo` in `demo`
```

how import the mod file to test file?

Comment: Assuming the package is actually named `demo`. You seem to have forgotten to add `pub mod lifetime_demo;` in `lib.rs`

Answer (score 1):

Tests in the `tests` directory, *outside* of the `src` directory are integration tests, which can only access your crate as a library, just as any end user of your library would. That means you need to import the crate in the tests and items are only accessible there if they are made public from the library, i.e. exported from `lib.rs`.

If you need to test private items or if your crate is not a library then put tests inside modules within the `src` directory instead.

Typically this is done within the same file as the code you are testing, e.g.:

```
// src/lifetime_demo/mod.rs

pub mod lifetime_mod {
    pub fn show() {}
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_trait() {
        lifetime_mod::show();
    }
}
```

If your project is a binary, not a library, then this will allow you to remove the `lib.rs` and just test the internals directly.

Comment: This won't run the tests either because `src/lifetime_demo/mod.rs` is not part of the module tree as @vallentin noted. If it was a visibility error, the error would have been something along the lines of ``error[E0603]: module `lifetime_demo` is private``

Comment: It _will_ run the test if the module is declared in `main.rs`. I think it's a fair assumption that this is the case, even though OP didn't mention it, because they also didn't mention any problems actually running the binary.